# Pine Script not matching candle pattern

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, candlestick-chart

I have a simple Pine-script that should identify a 5 candle pattern as follows:

- red candle, red candle, red candle, green candle, red candle

When I run it, it does match some correct patterns but I also get matches for:

- red candle, red candle, red candle, green candle, green candle

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
//@version=5    
strategy("Five Candle strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding = 1000)

red_candle = close < open
green_candle = open > close

// find a 5 candle pattern to the left of candle[0] as follows -> red,red,red,green,red
find_candle_pattern = red_candle[5] and red_candle[4] and red_candle[3] and green_candle[2] and red_candle[1]

if find_candle_pattern 
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, qty=10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two are actually the same.

```
red_candle = close < open
green_candle = open > close
```

A green candle is defined as

```
green_candle = close >= open
```

Comment: Rookie mistake on my part, thank you, the pattern is matching as it should now.

Can I ask a follow up question please? I would expect the 'buy' signal to appear on the candle immediately after the pattern is matched but instead it appears on the 2nd candle after the pattern is matched, is that correct or incorrect?

Comment: By default it will enter a position on the open of the next candle. You can add `process_orders_on_close=true` to your `strategy()` call and make it enter when a bar closes.

Comment: Many thanks, that works. Would have taken me ages to find that setting.